# Direction on how to run PowerShell script to create email box on Exchange server

Tags: c#, exchange-server

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: users have a need to create an email address through a web app (basically, it uses existing information to create custom, unique email addresses). Currently, the web app just generates the name, then they turn it over to us, and we run a PS script on Exchange to create the box. I'd like the box to be created when they request an email on the web app. There's probably like 10 ways to do this, but I'm thinking it would be a webservice that passes the email name to a Windows app on Exchange that executes the script and returns Success/Failure/Etc.. Does this seem viable. I'm not sure how to thread the process of running the PS script. Does anyone have any thoughts? I'm not looking for someone to write the code, but perhaps have some architectural ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods but the "easiest" one that pops into my head is as follows:

1. User logs into create-an-address web app
2. They submit a request into the app which stores the data in a SQL table (if exists)
3. STSS/DTS package produces a CSV output of date+ new entries and drops it into a Temp directory
4. Or skip the database and create/append a daily CSV-formatted file direct from the web app.
5. Scheduled job runs the powershell script which parses the CSV via for-each and creates users & mailboxes as needed.  If user exists, only add smtp to existing mailbox or whatever your requirements are
6. Powershell deletes the file if success or moves to another folder for investigation if failure occurs.

We've done similar data ingestions for various applications and it works well.  We add email events into the script for success/failures but we like the database approach because can ingest the CSV status with other STSS packages for historical reporting